# Jenkins job filter regular expression just doesn't work

Tags: regex, jenkins

My Jenkins version is 2.7.8, I have job like Email_AAA Email_BBB Email_CCC etc
i created a view and set the filter with following Regular Expression：
^Email.*$

But nothing is returned
I didn't find anything related to this in log.
Any possible clues?

Thanks.
-Neo

Comment: Try `Email_\S+`.

Comment: Agreed, Jenkins does not seem to understand actual RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a view of all job start with XXX use XXX.*

if you want a view that contain XXX use .* XXX.*

Comment: i tried Email.* or .*Email.* but neither works, i agree the regex is correct but is there any other setting i need to look at?  thanks.

Comment: did you try Email.* ?

Comment: can yu post a screen shoot of the job list and your filter ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saved me after whole day struggle. But Why does it ask a extra "." in it? I thought it is similar to "XXX*" not sure why it needs "XXX.*" ! Weired.

Answer (score 1):

to all those who are still coming to this question and leaving disappointed

try 
[image]

if this checkbox is not selected, you can filter only root level objects (pipelines/jobs/folders etc.) not child object

Comment: OK, But can you answer above question:  But Why does it ask a extra "." in it? I thought it is similar to "XXX*" not sure why it needs "XXX.*" ! Weired

Comment: @Krishna When you state a regex like `XXX*`, it means that `XXX` can be matched 0 or more times. This would only be a partial match of the String. When you state `.*` it means: `. -> Any character except newline`, `* -> 0 or more times`. This would then be a full match for the whole Jobname, because the regex will also match whatever comes after the `XXX` your trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why it may not work if no columns are added to the view.